# Anylogic PLE Code Completion not working Mac

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to activate code completion on mac. I have no other shortcuts mapped to Option+Space. When I press the keys nothing happens. I have tried to map it manually in the settings but can't see the code completion option.

Can anyone advise what the command is in preferences?

Cheers
Lee

Answer (score 2):

It can be finicky... Restart AnyLogic first. If that does not work close it.

Then look for the `.AnyLogic...` folder.

On Windows, it sits in `C:/Users/[MyProfile]/.AnyLogicYourVersion`

In it, delete the `Workspace 8.7` folder.